# Weird PHP not displaying over local ip address

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2

I have the following setup below:

```
Amazon EC2 instance.
IPs:
192.168.1.200 = eth0 = x.x.x.x public ip address
192.168.2.200 = eth1

Apps:
Apache
  vhosts:
       -domain.tld
PHP
```

The strange part is this. When I try to browse domain.tld over public ip address, its working fine. But when I browse it through 192.168.2.200, it will keep waiting until no display coming out in the browser. A simple index.php with a text "test" inside is working fine. Only when the php codes like phpinfo() will not be working.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem in php or apache or my network? I have already open all ports on the firewall but the problem still persist.

Thanks.

Comment: how do you have an EC2 instance with a local host ip?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - it's due to incorrect network routing table on the EC2 server including blocking of traffic that rectified through playing security settings.

Thanks to your comment @Dagon.